# How does Hand of the Apprentice interact with rogue abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, rogue, sneak-attack

My Arcane Trickster took the *Universalist* School (as a wizard). Which has the **Hand of the Apprentice** ability.

1. Since it does meet the 30 feet requirement for range, can he use his Sneak Attack with the Hand of the Apprentice ability?

He also has **Finesse Training** (from unchained rogue) with the rapier which allows Dex mod to damage instead of Str.

2. Would his Dex or Str affect his (Hand of the Apprentice) damage since his rapier damage is based on Dex?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 6):

#### Yes, Hand of the Apprentice can be used to make sneak attacks.

From the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo-arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/universalist/) (*emphasis mine*):

> As a standard action, you can make a single attack using a melee weapon at a *range of 30 feet*. This attack is treated as a *ranged attack* with a thrown weapon, except that you add your Intelligence modifier on the attack roll instead of your Dexterity modifier (damage still relies on Strength).

Hand of the Apprentice is a ranged attack with a range of 30 feet.

From the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/ROGUE-unchained/#Sneak_Attack) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Sneak Attack:** ... The rogue’s attack deals extra damage anytime her target would be denied a Dexterity bonus to AC (whether the target actually has a Dexterity bonus or not), or when the rogue flanks her target. This extra damage is 1d6 at 1st level, and increases by 1d6 every 2 rogue levels thereafter. *Ranged attacks can count as sneak attacks only if the target is within 30 feet.* ...

Sneak attack works with ranged attacks as long as the target is within 30 feet. Since Hand of the Apprentice is a ranged attack with a maximum range of 30 feet, it can always trigger sneak attack (assuming the target is denied its Dex bonus).

#### No, Finesse Training does not work on Hand of the Apprentice attacks.

From the [PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/ROGUE-unchained/#Finesse_Training_Ex) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Finesse Training (Ex):** ... Whenever she makes a successful *melee attack* with the selected weapon, she adds her Dexterity modifier instead of her Strength modifier to the damage roll. ...

Note that Finesse Training only applies to *melee* attacks. As established above, Hand of the Apprentice attacks are *ranged* attacks rather than melee attacks. Therefore Finesse Training cannot change their damage bonus to be based on Dex rather than Str.